# cant get find() or any jquery standard selector to work

Tags: jquery, selector

Hi,

I am using this jquery to get contents out of 2 divs on another page and then insert them into 2 divs on my page:

```
$.get("fruits.php", function(data){
  var pears = $("#mainDiv", data);
  var apples = $("#subDiv", data);

   $("#cont1").html(pears);
   $("#cont2").html(apples);
});
```

but nothing happens, no content is fetched at all and I get no error on the console. I also tried:

```
$(data).find("#mainDiv");
$(data).find("#subDiv");
```

but no use either. Why is that? Im using the latest version of jquery.

By the way, the source page looks like this:

```
<div id="mainDiv">some pears</div>
<div id="subDiv">some apples</div>
```

Whereas my page looks like this:

```
<div id="cont1"></div>
<div id="cont2"></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it. Do you mind to elaborate a little more?

Comment: @VLAZ Your explanation is very misleading since `$(htmlString).find(selector)` is perfectly valid way to work with the ajax html response whereas `$("#mainDiv")` will search the DOM not the html response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `$(selector, context)` call uses the `find()` method internally. As you have no root element, and the targets you're looking for are siblings, there is no parent element to *find* anything from.

To correct this issue you can either wrap the HTML you return from `fruits.php` in a parent element, or use `filter()` instead:

```js
let data = '<div id="mainDiv">some pears</div><div id="subDiv">some apples</div>';

// inside AJAX callback:
let $data = $(data);
var $pears = $data.filter("#mainDiv");
var $apples = $data.filter("#subDiv");

$("#cont1").html($pears);
$("#cont2").html($apples);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont1"></div>
<div id="cont2"></div>
```

Comment: Okay but your example is when taking data from within the same page. Not an external page which is the case I am exposing here.

Comment: It is the exact same as when taking data from any source. Clearly I used the static `data` variable in the example as I obviously can't replicate AJAX in a snippet, this is why I commented the code you need to use in your actual AJAX callback.

Comment: okay I managed to adapt your code to my situation and it seems to work. One more question. I want to get only the CONTENTS, not the containers. I tried `var $apples = $data.filter("#subDiv > *");` but didnt work.

Comment: That should work. Possibly try `$('#subDiv').html()` instead, depending on your exact use case. I'd suggest starting a new question about that if you're having issues.

Comment: neither works. Any suggestion for the question? Selectors not working for ajax callback should suffice?

Comment: The answer I provided above solves the issue you originally posted. If you have another problem you require help with, you should start a new question providing all relevant information about it.,

Comment: posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794722/selectors-not-selecting-children-nor-contents-when-doing-an-ajax-callback

Answer (score 0):

This slight modification to @RoryMcCrossan's answer takes care of situations where the target `div` is not a top-level element in which case `filter()` will not work.

```js
let data = '<div id="mainDiv">some pears</div><div id="subDiv">some apples</div>';

// inside AJAX callback:
let $data = $('<div/>').html(data);
var $pears = $data.find("#mainDiv").html();
var $apples = $data.find("#subDiv").html();

$("#cont1").html($pears);
$("#cont2").html($apples);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cont1"></div>
<div id="cont2"></div>
```