# Selectors not selecting children nor contents when doing an Ajax callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi,

I want to get the contents out of 2 divs on a page that looks like this:

```
<div id="mainDiv">some pears</div>
<div id="subDiv">some apples</div>
```

i tried this code:

```
let $data = $(data);
var $pears = $data.filter("#mainDiv");
var $apples = $data.filter("#subDiv");

$("#cont1").html($pears);
$("#cont2").html($apples);
```

but this is importing the containers as well which I dont need, only the contents so I tried:

```
var $pears = $data.filter("#mainDiv > *");
```

but now nothing is being imported. Why is that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no elements inside the ones shown so using the selector `"#mainDiv > *"` returns no matches. Text nodes are not considered elements

Try just getting the inner html instead

```
var pears = $data.filter("#mainDiv").html();
$("#cont1").html(pears);
```